# How to encode a String with \n and \n in c#?

Tags: c#

I want to encode a string which has \n and \r . The backslash('\') should be encoded as %5c .
How to do that in c# ?
While Using HttpUtility.UrlEncode(string), it encodes backslash('\') as %0a.
I want to encode it to %5c.

Comment: Do you mean your original string actually has a backslash followed by an n, or that it has a newline character? Please provide a [mcve] - it'll make a lot of things clearer.

Comment: Why do you want this? What's the original string? In the compiled string these are actual newline and line feed characters, not backslashes and `n`s.  The URL encoding is correct. If `n` was meant to be an actual character, the original string is wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can get the solution in the following way:

```
string inputData = "Hello\r\nAshutosh\\Kushawaha";
string encodedData = WebUtility.UrlEncode(inputData);
Console.WriteLine(encodedData);
    
    //Output is 
   Hello%0D%0AAshutosh%5cKushawaha
```

Here, we can see that backslashes have been replaced with "%5c" and line breaks "\r\n" are encoded with "%Od%Oa" which is the standard encoding for newlines in URLs.

Answer (score 1):

**Use the following :**

```
var s = "I have a a string like this \\nThis is a new line string\\nThis is another-new-line";
Console.Write(Regex.Unescape(s));
```

**Please find the working demo [here](https://ideone.com/fork/KCxvKR)**.